# django how to hide specific form filed and loop data input

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I just follow the tutorial and got stuck when I saw form field not use `<input>` tag.

here my code

`model.py`

```
class Employee(models.Model):
companyid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
return reverse("system:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

here my `system/templates/system/emp_form.html`

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and here my `view.py`

```
class EmployeeCreateView(CreateView):
fields = ('nik','name')
model = models.Employee

def form_valid(self, form):
self.object = form.save(commit=False)
empcount = models.TempEmp.objects.filter(status=0).count()
self.object.companyid = CID + str(datetime.date().now()) + str(empcount+1)
self.object.save()
return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

problem 1.

`emp_form.html` use `{{ form.as_p }}` that show all the form, I want to hide specific field like in my case is `companyid` that I need to computer generated.

problem 2.

can I use `+` for str on `CID + str(datetime.date().now()) + str(empcount+1)`

or any other solution maybe?

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want the companyid in template use `exclude` to hide.

Comment: @RajaSimon can you give m some example?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ModelForm exclude to hide the form being render

```
class EmployeeCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ['nik','name']
    exclude = ['companyid']
```

Answer (score 1):

OR, in the model itself, you can set editable to false. This makes it so it doesn't show up in any forms.

```
class Employee(model.Models):
     companyid = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
```